# Can Swing + Servlets be considered a web application?

Tags: java, json, swing, servlets

The UI part of my program is written in Java-Swing while the server-side is written using Java Servlets. The client sends a request in a JSON-form to the servlet and the servlet returns a JSON as well. All of the tasks that involve talking to the database are done in the server. That means the user won't be able to login to his account without connecting to the web server.

Can I still call this a web application even though the client program is not a web browser?

Comment: It's not a "web application" but it *is* a JavaEE application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "web" in web application does not say anything about "world wide web" or "website", it simply means network. The content of a web-based application can be delivered in multiple ways (http, webservice, socket, ...) at the same time, so its does not mean a browser has to be involved. It does not depend on the technic. For example, if you are connected to your app from your swing application, *maybe* I am connected to the same servlet from Firefox, than it would be a web-application and a none-web-application at the same time. [;)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat)

Answer (score 3):

No It's not a web application.

> A [web-based application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) is any application that uses a web browser as a client

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it that, since it doesn't have the "web" part. It's essentially a client-server application.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take the opposite stance of everyone else and say that the server part of it is.  Since you're using HTTP Servlets, you're using web protocols as a transport infrastructure.  The client part is a Swing application, but you could swap that component out with a browser based client so make the full application a "web" application.